# Bitbucket doesn't recognize my Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, bitbucket

I have my iOS Swift project hosted in `Bitbucket` and I noticed every other project `(PHP, NodeJS, Android)` they have the little icon and they recognize the programming language, but it doesn't happen for my Swift project.

Since I'm using **cocoapods**, the fact that my project is now inside a *workspace* might have something to do with it, how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not BitBucket customer support/bug report/feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket doesn't have a default logo for swift project, you can set the language and logo on the repository settings.